# Different reputation in my profile page, is it a bug?

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation

[image]

Why I have two different reputation in a same page? It's a bug, isn't it?

Comment: Probably just a caching issue.

Comment: now both value is 385 :-? so difficult to understand

Comment: Maybe someone upvoted one of your answers, and then retracted the upvote.

Comment: now it is 385-395, does stackoverflow use memcache :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The page is cached & it does take some time ( give an hour or so ) to sync rep network wide.

Answer (score 7):

Sathya is correct - this is due to caching elements of the page.  Look again and you will find all of your reputation scores are now synced.

---

*Update:* We've now added magic sauce so that reputation and badges sync on the current site.

*Note:* it may still be up to **10 minutes** (cache duration) out of date for the *other* sites, since it's not really reasonable to keep it real-time across the entire network.