# Why does Superuser say I have higher rep than I really have?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Different reputation in my profile page, is it a bug?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114485/different-reputation-in-my-profile-page-is-it-a-bug)

I recently deleted a post where I had one up-vote and one down-vote (I didn't read the question and didn't really answer the question) and so I am back to a total rep of one on Stack Overflow, but my SuperUser user info still shows I have a total reputation of 11 on Stack Overflow. Why is this? Is there some nightly check of the rep on the different accounts or is it a bug?

Comment: The information in the Accounts tab is cached. You have to wait a bit for it to update...