# My Meta SO rep showing wrong on my user profile on network sites except Meta SO

Tags: bug, reputation

For example: My profile for Skeptics looks like this:

[image: skeptics]

But my Meta Stack Overflow profile looks like this:

[image: MetaSO]

All the sites I've checked show my (incorrect) Meta Stack Overflow rep as 1 on my profile. It shows as the (correct) rep of 101 on the top of the page on Meta:

[image: my rep]

EDIT: People have upvoted this question, so my Meta rep has changed and my new rep now displays correctly across the network.

Comment: Possibly caching? Not sure how long it takes for the network sites to update, usually... Considering your MSO account is very new, can't say for sure.

Comment: Now that my rep on meta is 111, its showing correctly on skeptics.

Comment: There is caching, but [things should never be four _days_ out of date](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114552/131713).

Comment: @PopularDemand: Well, search me.